# Date format set to dd/mm/YY returning Y-m-d after search validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, date-format

I have an odd behaviour on a website I work on.
The datepicker is set to dd/mm/yyyy and works fine on one of the pages displaying results, but on the other one, after submiting and the page getting refreshed, it changes the format displayed to y-m-d.
I'm using foundation datepicker plugin on a Phalcon/php built website.
Have you met this issue before ? Any leads ? thanks !

```
"use strict";

$(function(){

    // Datepicker
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var datepickerCommonOptions = {
        language: "fr",
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        leftArrow: "<",
        rightArrow: ">"
    };

    //CODE INITIALIZING ON THE PAGE ON WHICH IT CHANGES DATE FORMAT

    // Field used on the calendar view.
    var dateFromFilter = $("#dateFromFilter")
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
        }
    }))
    .on("changeDate", function(ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > dateToFilter.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            dateToFilter.update(newDate);
        }
        dateFromFilter.hide();
        $("#dateToFilter")[0].focus();
    })
    .data("datepicker");

    // Field used on the calendar view.
    var dateToFilter = $("#dateToFilter")
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= dateFromFilter.date.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
        }
    }))
    .on("changeDate", function() {
        dateToFilter.hide();
    })
    .data("datepicker");


    //CODE INITIALIZING ON THE PAGE ON WHICH EVERYTHINK WORKS FINE

    // Field used on the sales results view
    var dateFromFilterUnlimited = $("#dateFromFilter.unlimitedDateFilter")
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions))
    .on("changeDate", function(ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > dateToFilter.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            dateToFilter.update(newDate);
        }
        dateFromFilterUnlimited.hide();
        $("#dateToFilter")[0].focus();
    })
    .data("datepicker");

    // Field working with the dateFrom used on the calendar view.
    var dateToFilterUnlimited = $("#dateToFilter.unlimitedDateFilter")
    .fdatepicker($.extend({}, datepickerCommonOptions, {
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= dateFromFilterUnlimited.date.valueOf() ? "disabled" : "";
        }
    }))
    .on("changeDate", function() {
        dateToFilterUnlimited.hide();
    })
    .data("datepicker");
});
```

[image: Here's a capture of when I set the date]

[image: And this is after I submit and the page refreshes]

Comment: show us the code....a mcve

Comment: Sorry. Here it is

Answer (score 0):

If you use `type="date"` then input value will always be formated like *Y-m-d*.
Visually it will depend on both platform and browser but in the end value will use *Y-m-d* format.
And datepicker will work with this with errors.

You have 2 solutions:

1. *Remove datepicker* and just rely on the browser's default input rendering and manually calculate `Y-m-d` format.
2. *Change type to text*, so datepicker will work fine.

Check these manuals for more info and examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date